# How to detect a number in my Linked List of Strings, and get the value

Tags: string, sorting, split, linked-list, iterator

I need to sort my Linked List, the problem is that each of my Linked List elements are Strings with sentences. So the question is... how to detect each number in my Linked List and get the value?.

I tried to split my linked list so I can pass trough each element.

```
private LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
list.add("Number One: 1")
list.add("Number Three: 3")
list.add("Number two:2")



for(Iterator<String> iterator =list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) 
        {
            String string = iterator.next();
            for (String word : string.split(" ")){
            }
```

I also tried with  "if((word.contains("1") || (word.contains("2")...." inside the for loop,  and then pass the value "word" to Double... but I think is not very smart

So my goal is this Output (Number One: 1 , Number Two: 2, Number Three: 3), therefore I need the value of each number first.

Answer (score 0):

why not use tryParse on the string,

```
for (String word : string.split(" ")){
    int outvalue
    if(int.TryParse(word, outvalue)){
        //DoSomething with result
    }
}
```